# Querying Visual studio 2010 load test data from SQL table

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have setup a load test in Visual studio 2010, run it several times, and then exported the data into an SQL database.  It should be the typical way of doing this.  It has all these standard tables:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billbar/archive/2006/02/10/what-is-the-data-in-the-vsts-load-test-results-store.aspx

I am try to query the "Time to first Byte" for a specific requestURI in a test.

Any thoughts on how to put together this query?  Where table is the "Time to first byte" for a specific URI actually stored in?  Is there a website that lists common queries for these load test databases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [LoadTestRunId]
      ,[CounterId]
      ,[InstanceId]
      ,[LoadTestItemId]
      ,[InstanceName]
      ,[CumulativeValue]
      ,[OverallThresholdRuleResult]
  FROM [LoadTest2010].[dbo].[LoadTestPerformanceCounterInstance] where 
  LoadTestItemId = 12  -- The specific element in the web page I'm interested in
  and LoadTestRunId = 127 -- The specefic load test run I am using
  and CounterId = 78  -- The time to first byte metric
```